# E-mail Address to Inform Site Staff

Tags: support

Didn't I read something regarding an e-mail address for any/all sites that was team@this->domain? I just got a notification that my message to team@this->domain hasn't been accepted.

1. Does it exist?
2. Is it functioning?
3. Has it blocked Google/GMail?
4. Who does it notify? SE Staff and/or Moderators Pro Tempore?
5. Is it team@so (se?) only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

team@stackexchange.com is only for mailing when you have issues that shouldn't be discussed in public and that you couldn't work out with one of the mods.

All regular questions should simply go onto the relevant Meta site. If it's for Gaming here, if it's a question that affects the whole network on Meta.SO

Answer (score 3):

The address team@stackexchange.com is only for mailing when you have issues that shouldn't be discussed in public and that you couldn't work out with one of the mods.

All regular questions should simply go onto the relevant Meta site. If it's for Gaming here, if it's a question that affects the whole network on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

If you want to catch a gaming moderator, your best option is one of:

1. Use "flag for moderation attention"
2. Post a meta topic about the subject here, just like you've done
3. Access [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35) and "ping" a specific moderator - for example, writing "@Oak" will draw my attention.

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: Accept his instead ;-)

Comment: I took the liberty of "merging" the answers /cc @Ivo

Comment: Well delete mine, so @Oak's can be accepted @Juan